# How to control what APIs a client can access using WSO2's API Manager

Tags: api, security, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm reading the API Manager documentation and I noticed the following:

- Self-sign up for API consumption

This implies that the client can decide what APIs they access. I don't want this. I need to control what data the user can access. How would I do this with the API manager?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can control the Visibility of APIs based on user roles. Users who self signup will have subscriber role. So you can set the API visibility to some specific roles (who has subscribe permissions) other than role 'subscriber'.

Check the following doc which explains the usage of 'Visibility' field in Add API Page.

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AM131/Adding+an+API